# Toggle leaflet legend on/off via eventListener

Tags: javascript, function, leaflet, event-listener

I'm trying to go for an on/off toggle when "Legend" is clicked in the navbar. However, when I'm constructing the function for `addEventListener`, I keep receiving a type error. I understand this is because `info` is not defined but I'm not sure how to define it so the `style display` can be changed to `block` and it will appear on the map when `Legend` is clicked in the nav bar.

Any suggestions to point me in the right direction?

**HTML:**

```
<!--Navbar-->
    <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="logo">
            <h4> Earthquake Feed</h4>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li><a href="#simpleModal" id="aboutModal">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#legend" id="legend">Legend</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
/*CSS for legend*/
.info {
  padding: 6px 8px;
  font: 14px/16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: white;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: none;
  }

.legend {
  background-color: “black”;
  line-height: 26px;
  color: #555;
  width: auto;
```

**Javascript:**

```
// adds legend to map
var legend = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});

legend.onAdd = function(map) {
    var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend'),
        magnitudes = [0,1,2,3,4,5];

    div.innerHTML += "<h4 style='margin:5px'>Magnitude</h4>" 
    div.innerHTML += '<i class="circleR" style=background:>' + '</i>' + "Recent" + '<br>'

    // loop through color intervals and generate a lable
    for (var i=0; i < magnitudes.length; i++) {
        div.innerHTML += 
                        '<i class="circle" style=background:' + getColor(magnitudes[i] + 1) + '></i>' +
                        magnitudes[i] + (magnitudes[i+1]?'&ndash;' + magnitudes[i+1] + '<br>': '+');
    }
    return div;
};
legend.addTo(map);

// toggles legend on and off
var legendLink = document.getElementById("legend");
legendLink.addEventListener('click', openLegend);
function openLegend(){
    info.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a DOM element that specifies the element you want to style.

```
function openLegend(){
    document.getElementByClass("legend").style.display = 'block';
}
```

should work for you.

Comment: Rather a query selector by class name?

Comment: @ghybs Yep, that would be better practice, I went for the Id selector because the OP has already used one.

Comment: OP targets `<a href="#legend" id="legend">Legend</a>` with the id selector, but for their `L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend')` it will have only class

Comment: Duh, yeah. Edited. Tnx.